# comparing data of two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames and i want to compare the data of those two datasets in another dataframe.

my objective is to compare all column of two dataframes and also check their texts . i want to check both the data base are consistent.

Note: rows and column in both data frame can vary

```
df1 <- data.frame(MAN=c(6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8),MANi=c("OD","NY","CA","CA","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL","NY","OD","CA","OD"),
                  nune=c("akas","mani","juna","mau","nuh","kil","kman","nuha","huna","kman","nuha","huna","mani"),
                  klay=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2),emial=c("dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd"),Pass=c("Low","High","Low","Low","High","Low","High","High","Low","High","High","High","Low"),fri=c("KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP","TGA","KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK"),
                  mkl=c("m","f","m","m","f","m","m","f","m","m","f","m","m"),kin=c("Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Rec","Sent","Rec"),munc=c("Car","Bus","Truk","Cyl","Bus","Car","Bus","Bus","Bus","Car","Car","Cyl","Car"),
                  lone=c("Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man"),wond=c("tko","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kent","bho","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kilt"))

df2 <- data.frame(MAN=c(6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8,8,6),MANi=c("OD","NY","CA","CA","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL","ny","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL"),
                  nune=c("akas","mani","juna","mau","nuh","kil","kman","nuha","huna","kman","nuha","huna","mani","juna","mau"),
                  klay=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1),emial=c("dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC"),Pass=c("Low","High","Low","Low","High","Low","High","High","Low","High","High","High","Low","High","High"),fri=c("KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP","TGA","KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP"),
                  mkl=c("male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male"),kin=c("Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec"),munc=c("Car","Bus","Truk","Cyl","Bus","Car","Bus","Bus","Bus","Car","Car","Cyl","Car","Bus","Bus"),
                  lone=c("Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","man"),wond=c("tko","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kent","bho","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho"))




df1_long <- df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = "Names_df1",
    values_to = "options_df1"
  ) %>%   
  arrange(Names_df1,options_df1)

df2_long <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = "Names_df2",
    values_to = "options_df2"
  ) %>%   
  arrange(Names_df2,options_df2)
```

the output should be look like

[image]

below are inconsistency between data bases

[image]

Comment: This scenario is what I was referring to in your other question. If the amount of rows can differ how do you want to figure out when to compare two rows and when not? You really have three states here: Not present, not matching, matching. How do you figure out whether a row is not present or just different? There is no one answer to this and what to do depends on the application.

Comment: What Robin said above. As the question is now it is not really clear what you want (or it's not achievable). Also, the names in your expected results are not valid. Also it would be easier for others to test their answer if the expected result was in code form. It is generally never a good idea to post code or data as images...

Comment: there's a library called "‘compareDF" that may answer some of your problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(MAN=c(6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8),MANi=c("OD","NY","CA","CA","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL","NY","OD","CA","OD"),
                  nune=c("akas","mani","juna","mau","nuh","kil","kman","nuha","huna","kman","nuha","huna","mani"),
                  klay=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2),emial=c("dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd"),Pass=c("Low","High","Low","Low","High","Low","High","High","Low","High","High","High","Low"),fri=c("KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP","TGA","KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK"),
                  mkl=c("m","f","m","m","f","m","m","f","m","m","f","m","m"),kin=c("Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Rec","Sent","Rec"),munc=c("Car","Bus","Truk","Cyl","Bus","Car","Bus","Bus","Bus","Car","Car","Cyl","Car"),
                  lone=c("Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man"),wond=c("tko","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kent","bho","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kilt"))

df2 <- data.frame(MAN=c(6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8,8,6),MANi=c("OD","NY","CA","CA","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL","ny","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL"),
                  nune=c("akas","mani","juna","mau","nuh","kil","kman","nuha","huna","kman","nuha","huna","mani","juna","mau"),
                  klay=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1),emial=c("dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC"),Pass=c("Low","High","Low","Low","High","Low","High","High","Low","High","High","High","Low","High","High"),fri=c("KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP","TGA","KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP"),
                  mkl=c("male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male"),kin=c("Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec"),munc=c("Car","Bus","Truk","Cyl","Bus","Car","Bus","Bus","Bus","Car","Car","Cyl","Car","Bus","Bus"),
                  lone=c("Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","man"),wond=c("tko","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kent","bho","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho"))

df1_long <- df1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.double, as.character) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Names", values_to = "options") %>%   
  arrange(Names, options)

df2_long <- df2 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.double, as.character) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Names", values_to = "options") %>%   
  arrange(Names, options)

df1_long %>% 
  full_join(df2_long, by=c("Names", "options"), keep = TRUE) %>% 
  distinct(Names.x, options.x, Names.y, options.y) %>% 
  arrange(Names.x, Names.y,  options.x, options.y) %>% 
  mutate(
    consistant_names = !is.na(Names.x) & !is.na(Names.y),
    consistant_options = !is.na(options.x) & !is.na(options.y)
  )
```

output `df %>% head(10)`

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   Names.x options.x Names.y options.y consistant_names consistant_options
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <lgl>            <lgl>             
 1 emial   dd        emial   dd        TRUE             TRUE              
 2 emial   xyz       emial   xyz       TRUE             TRUE              
 3 emial   abc       NA      NA        FALSE            FALSE             
 4 fri     CHI       fri     CHI       TRUE             TRUE              
 5 fri     IND       fri     IND       TRUE             TRUE              
 6 fri     JYP       fri     JYP       TRUE             TRUE              
 7 fri     KKK       fri     KKK       TRUE             TRUE              
 8 fri     PAK       fri     PAK       TRUE             TRUE              
 9 fri     SRI       fri     SRI       TRUE             TRUE              
10 fri     TGA       fri     TGA       TRUE             TRUE
```

output `df %>% tail(10)`

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   Names.x options.x Names.y options.y consistant_names consistant_options
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <lgl>            <lgl>             
 1 Pass    High      Pass    High      TRUE             TRUE              
 2 Pass    Low       Pass    Low       TRUE             TRUE              
 3 wond    bho       wond    bho       TRUE             TRUE              
 4 wond    kent      wond    kent      TRUE             TRUE              
 5 wond    kilt      wond    kilt      TRUE             TRUE              
 6 wond    tko       wond    tko       TRUE             TRUE              
 7 NA      NA        emial   ABC       FALSE            FALSE             
 8 NA      NA        MANi    ny        FALSE            FALSE             
 9 NA      NA        mkl     female    FALSE            FALSE             
10 NA      NA        mkl     male      FALSE            FALSE
```

And one more important note.
There is one inaccuracy in your assignment. It's about using `names` with missing `options`. E.G. for `names_df2 = "eminal"` and `options_df2 = "ABC"` you'd like `names_df1 = "eminal"`.
Meanwhile, when `names_df2 = "mkl"` and `options_df2 = "male"` you want `names_df1 = NA`. You have to decide on one solution.

One of the possible solutions is this

```
df = df1_long %>% 
  full_join(df2_long, by=c("Names", "options"), keep = TRUE) %>% 
  distinct(Names.x, options.x, Names.y, options.y) %>% 
  arrange(Names.x, Names.y,  options.x, options.y) %>% 
  mutate(
    Names.x = ifelse(!is.na(Names.x), Names.x, Names.y),
    Names.y = ifelse(!is.na(Names.y), Names.y, Names.x),
    consistant_names = !is.na(Names.x) & !is.na(Names.y),
    consistant_options = !is.na(options.x) & !is.na(options.y)
  )
```

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Remember that on Stack Overflow you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.